# logging host 1.1.1.1 on Cisco C9300

Tags: cisco, logging, ios-xe

My Catalyst C9300s running IOS-XE have logging host 1.1.1.1 in the config by default. Is that because it is sending logs to it's internal logs store? I can't seem to find a straight answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

1.1.1.1 is Cloudflare DNS.  So that's not a valid syslog address.

Comment: But why is it defaulted on everyone?

Comment: @JukEboX It's not. Use `show run` and if there's a line `logging 1.1.1.1` it's been configured by someone.

Comment: Definitely not the default. Someone configured it that way at some point. They probably thought it would be neat to use that IP block locally on the network at some point but it belongs to cloudflare so it cannot be used by any organization but them.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer I will check one right out of the box.

Comment: It should not have any syslog host pre-configured in the default configuration from the manufacturer. Every Cisco router or switch I have ever seen has no default syslog server destination configured. How could they possibly know what server address to use? They certainly would not use a public IP address like that which belongs to another company.